# SQL find and replace error

Tags: mysql

I can not figure out (not sure what the error codes mean) what is wrong with the below `SQL` statement and I am do not have enough experience to troubleshoot it.  Thank you :).

```
UPDATE `dbo.Custom_PrimerSet`
SET `Hyperlink` = replace(Hyperlink, 'xxxx', 'pxlence')
```

**Error**

```
Error in table name or view name in UPDATE clause.
Error in set list in UPDATE clause.
Incomplete SET clause.
Unable to parse query text.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use both Hyperlink and 'Hyperlink'. If you make those consistent and correct does it work out better?

Correct in this case being to omit the quote in the update statement. At least that what works for me in a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4e4bb/1)

Comment: This could better go as a comment!

Comment: @PrerakSola: I disagree in that it is an answer that leads to the solution with actual spelling it out. However, I'll edit with a little more.